# How many ways can I replace the 0 in a string?

Tags: python

We say that integer A conforms to integer B if, in all positions where B has bits set to 1, A has corresponding bits set to 1.
For example:

```
00 0000 1111 0111 1101 1110 0000 1111(BIN) = 16,244,239 conforms to
00 0000 1100 0110 1101 1110 0000 0001(BIN) = 13,032,961, but
11 0000 1101 0111 0000 1010 0000 0101(BIN) = 819,399,173 does not conform to
00 0000 1001 0110 0011 0011 0000 1111(BIN) = 9,843,471.
```

that, given three unsigned 30-bit integers A, B and C, returns the number of unsigned 30-bit integers conforming to at least one of the given integers.

For example, for integers:

```
A = 11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,727,
B = 11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0011 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,631, and
C = 11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0110 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,679,
```

the function should return 8, since there are 8 unsigned 30-bit integers conforming to A, B or C, namely:

```
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0011 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,631,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0110 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,679,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0111 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,695,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,727,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,759,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,791,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,807,
11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111(BIN) = 1,073,741,823.
```

**Goal**

```
def solution(A,B,C):
   ...
   return number_of_compinations
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: For one number: calculate how many 0s it has (out conforming number would need to have all 1s, so we need to differ on 0s) and do 2^count. For 3 numbers, you gotta work on excluding the overlaps (see previous comment). I can recommend pen and paper to analyse it - despite long numbers here, the difference is small and easy to analyse by hand. (Hint: it will be basically the same but on overlaps. Use binary operator `|` on numbers to merge the 1s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that works for 3 numbers:

```
def zero_count(n,k):
    return bin(n)[2:].zfill(k).count('0')

def count_extensions(a,b,c,k):
    #include individual items
    s = 2**zero_count(a,k)
    s += 2**zero_count(b,k)
    s += 2**zero_count(c,k)

    #exclude pairs
    s -= 2**zero_count(a|b,k)
    s -= 2**zero_count(a|c,k)
    s -= 2**zero_count(b|c,k)

    #include all 3:
    s += 2**zero_count(a|b|c,k)
    return s

a = 1073741727
b = 1073741631
c = 1073741679

print(count_extensions(a,b,c,30)) #8
```

It uses the 3-set [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The full principle would be required if you want to generalize to more than 3 numbers.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much. that works just fine, can you also help with this ? [SparseBinaryDecomposition](https://app.codility.com/programmers/trainings/9/sparse_binary_decomposition/)

Comment: @alial-karaawi Seems straightforward, but it would be another question.

Comment: I posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70800746/sparse-binary-decomposition

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do:

Use bitwise & between numbers. Then count the number of `1` in the result:

```
a = 8
b = 7

c = a&b

strc = bin(c)[2:] #remove 0b at the begining of the string

# count 1
print(strc.count("1"))
# prints 0
```

Comment: This provides 28 (or at least more than 27) with the user's input, not 8 as asked.