# Sparse Binary Decomposition

Tags: python

A non-negative integer N is called sparse if its binary representation does not contain two consecutive bits set to 1. For example, 41 is sparse, because its binary representation is "101001" and it does not contain two consecutive 1s. On the other hand, 26 is not sparse, because its binary representation is "11010" and it contains two consecutive 1s.

Two non-negative integers P and Q are called a sparse decomposition of integer N if P and Q are sparse and N = P + Q.

For example:

```
8 and 18 are a sparse decomposition of 26 (binary representation of 8 is "1000", binary representation of 18 is "10010");
9 and 17 are a sparse decomposition of 26 (binary representation of 9 is "1001", binary representation of 17 is "10001");
2 and 24 are not a sparse decomposition of 26; though 2 + 24 = 26, the binary representation of 24 is "11000", which is not sparse.
```

I need a function that, given a non-negative integer N, returns any integer that is one part of a sparse decomposition of N. The function should return −1 if there is no sparse decomposition of N.

For example, given N = 26 the function may return 8, 9, 17 or 18, as explained in the example above. All other possible results for N = 26 are 5, 10, 16 and 21.

- **I tried this**: Which works when N=26, 1166, 1031. But id does not work for very big numbers like `74901729` because of runtime error (timeout)

```
import re
def solution(N):

    for i in range(N):
        x = N-i
        is_x_sparse = not re.findall('11+', bin(x))
        is_i_sparse = not re.findall('11+', bin(i))
        if is_x_sparse and is_i_sparse:
            return i
```

Comment: Ok, now show us what you have done, and what error you get. "Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000]."Stackoverflow is not a homework service

Comment: yes, do it and update your question. and  make the overall question more understandable

Comment: Hi @alial-karaawi, this is an interesting question. I would be interested in your attempts and willing to look at them and try to find problems of what you have tried so far. (Please ping me here using my username.) Also, just out of curiosity: What is the bit picture of your question, i.e. what do you need it for?

Comment: Wouldn't `(x & 0x55555555, x & 0xAAAAAAAA)` be a solution for any `x`? The masks have alternating bits so the result will be a sparse decomposition

Comment: I update my question and I added my attempt

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks, I just added it as an answer. I think it works for any non-negative `x`: for x=0, it outputs (0,0), for x=1, it outputs (1,0), for x=2, (0,2) and for x=3, (1,2), which should all be valid solutions

Answer (score 7):

As per my comment, one solution for any `x` is the pair `(x & 0x55555555, x & 0xAAAAAAAA)`, of which you can return any of the two elements.

Now, why does this work? Let's look at the masks in binary:

```
0x55555555 = 0b01010101010101010101010101010101
0xAAAAAAAA = 0b10101010101010101010101010101010
```

They both have alternating 1s and 0s, so the result of the bitwise and of any number with one of the masks will never have two consecutive ones.

The only missing thing is whether the two values sum to the original `x`. This is indeed the case: each bit of `x` that was set to `1` will be in exactly one of the two items, and during the addition no carry will ever be generated (when doing the sum, we never sum two 1s). So the addition reduces to the binary or of the operands, and the result will be the original `x`.

As a final note, the masks I mentioned are 32bit, but can be adapted to any width by extending or reducing the same pattern.

Comment: This works so long as the solution is allowed to be zero or N (when N is itself sparse). While the question conditions don't strictly prohibit this (P and Q must only be non-negative), it means that there is a valid sparse decomposition of any N, and the solution will never return -1. Knowing that this question originates from an online coding challenge, either the original is arguably a trick question, or the question intended to treat zero and sparse N as an invalid decomposition but failed to express this clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't short-circuit when it finds `'11'` in the binary expansion of `i` but instead finds all matches in both `i` and `N-i`.

Here is a solution which uses the simple `in` operator on strings rather than `re`. It also iterates up to `(N+1)//2` rather than `N`. It takes advantage both of the short-circuiting nature of `in` and the short-circuiting nature of `and`:

```
def solution(N):

    for i in range((N+1)//2):
        x = N-i
        if not '11' in bin(i) and not '11' in bin(x):
            return i
    return -1
```

It is noticeably faster on `74901729`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def solution(N):
    # Implement your solution here
    if N == 0:
        return 0
    if N == 1:
        return 1
    for P in range(1,N):
        if P <= N/2:
            s1 = None
            s2 = None
            s3 = None
            s4 = None
            Q = N - P
            s1 = format(P,'b')
            s2 = s1[1:] + '0'
            if int(s1,2) & int(s2,2) == 0:
                s3 = format(Q, 'b')
                s4 = s3[1:] + '0'
                if int(s3,2) & int(s4,2) == 0:
                    return P
    return -1
```

this work properly but failed in performance ,however you can find 100% solution under this link:
https://gist.github.com/tcarrio/f90efb54c72cc84c2aa05ce8fc7d5e7d